# Android image from URL button

Tags: android, image, url, bitmap

I have a button and when I click it I want to import an image from URL 
I tried many codes but did not work 
I want it just the url input and then it gets the image and put it as the result

this is my code for the camera ,

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

made same with the browser button , changed IMAGE_CAPTURE to INTERNET but it doesn't work

Comment: note*= I want the url image to gets in the bitmap like the camera one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting an image from the internet is little bit more difficult,

you will need to first download it, and then load it in your application.

```
Bitmap bmImg;
void downloadFile(String fileUrl){
      URL myFileUrl =null;          
      try {
           myFileUrl= new URL(fileUrl);
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
      }
      try {
          Handler handler = new Handler();
          new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                 HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
                   conn.setDoInput(true);
                   conn.connect();
                   InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                   handler.post(new Runnable() {
                       bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                       imView.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
                   });
            }

          }).start();


      } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
      }
 }
```

[code source](http://en.androidwiki.com/wiki/Loading_images_from_a_remote_server)